# Control - M view last runtime

Tags: control-m

I am trying to see when the job was last run in control-m. Read other posts but did not find anything pointing to it. Any idea?

Edit: I am at the 'Monitoring' tab - I can see the parent job run-timings, but not the individual job run-times and statuses.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: is "control-m" a program? Or are you referring to something that happens when you type control-m when running some other program?

Comment: It is the program/software I am referring to - hence the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to right click on the job and look for Statistics.  Control-M maintains, by default, the last 20 runs of the job.